# Creating Dataset for LSTM TimeSeries with less memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

so currently i have a time series data with the shape of (8392, 41164), to feed it into my lstm model, i need to reshape it into 3D dimension, and i used this code to create the dataset

```
def create_dataset(X, y, time_steps):
Xs, ys = [], []
for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
    v = X[i:(i + time_steps)]
    Xs.append(v)        
    ys.append(y[i + time_steps])
return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)
```

and it return the data in shape of (8378, 14, 41164), but it consume about 50GB of RAM, is there any solutions to create it with less memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered committing the windowized dataset to the disk? I would then probably use a B-Tree or something to make indexing easier, but this is a good first step. You can store the data on disk by, inside your for-loop, framing 1024 windows at a time and storing them as "data_{i}.csv" for each page. This could be done like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
page_size = 1024
page_i = 1
for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
    pageX = []
    pageY = []
    for j in range(page_size):
        v = X[i:(i + time_steps)]
        pageX.append(v)
        pageY.append(y[i + time_steps])
    page_df = pd.DataFrame([{'X': pageX[j], 'Y': pageY[j]} for j in range(page_size)])
    page_df.to_csv(f"data_{page_i}.csv", index=False)
    page_i += 1
    Xs.extend(pageX)
    ys.extend(pageY)
return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)
```

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.

David

Comment: Thanks David, i think i can try it..i'll report the result here

Comment: Just note that this on its own won't reduce the memory load. You'll want to access the data from the disk as well, so you can only access it in slices that need to be concatenated together after the fact. If this is being used for some ML project, I recommend training the algorithm in pieces on one page at a time, that way no more than 1024 windows need be stored in memory at any point in time.

Comment: I'm planning to make prediction on that 41.164 features with lstm, but the ram memory ran out just because of creating the dataset so i can't fit the model with good hyperparameters

Comment: can you tell me more about this "I recommend training the algorithm in pieces on one page at a time, that way no more than 1024 windows need be stored in memory at any point in time." ?